# Problems with applying stashed changes

Tags: git, git-stash

I needed to push a quick fix for a bug, so I stashed the changes I was working on. After I finished the bug fix, I committed it, then pulled the changes from the repository, and then pushed my changes.

After this I ran `git stash apply`, which resulted in this message: `CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.js`

I resolved the conflict and staged my changes. However, when I try to run `git stash apply` again, I get the same conflict message again:  `CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in foo.js`

I'm not sure what to do--I'm clearly doing something wrong, but I have no idea what. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to run `git stash apply` *again*. Because the stashed changes are already applied. You may even want to start using `git stash pop` at some point instead, so that the changes are removed from stash after they're applied.

Comment: +1 for `stash pop`, which is indeed more appropriate than `stash apply`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I am missing a file, which is what was throwing me off, but that may be due to other reasons... Would there be a reason why creating a new file and then calling stash would drop the file?

Comment: stash doesn't save untracked files, probably you dropped the file at some point when pulling the changes and doing whatever you've been doing.